# Update cache when query string change in workbox routing

Tags: service-worker, workbox

Really don't find an answer to my question :(

I created a worker service like this to manage my css stored on a CDN

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new RegExp('https://static.domain.com/css/.*'),
    workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({cacheName: 'static-css-v0'}),
);
```

My url are like this, the query string is used to reload the style

```
https://static.domain.com/css/style.css?1
```

I can see that my css is well saved in the cache static-css-v0 with the name

```
/css/style.css
```

But my question, is my style well updated when the url is changed to https://static.domain.com/css/style.css?1 ?

What happen in this case, is the file in the cache updated?

Not clear in the documentation, I don't see sample with query string :(

Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you "ignoresearch : true"

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/805